# Pivot table representing data as parent/child rather than desired summary of totals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

Ok, so struggling with a pivot table and I'm not sure of how to phrase the title exactly, so apologies if it isn't 100% accurate.

Please ask for more information where it is lacking in my description.

Screenshot is below to get an idea what the table looks like currently and a target for how I'd like the data to be summarised.

I am helping run user acceptance tests at work and I need to produce a table that counts the number of passes/fails/withdrawn etc fields that are entered into the spreadsheet per test.
The tests are being run by different users in various browsers and I need to pull all of that down into a single summary so that we can see the total number of tests passed/failed/blank etc.

Ideally output, along these lines in order to summarise the total table:

```
P  11
F  2
W  1
PE 1
B  20
```

The P, F etc fields belong to the different browser/platform combinations, desktop or mobile and the browser type.

The problem I am having is that when I drop the device/browser values into the `Values` section on the table, rather than summarising across the board, Excel is creating them as parent/child relationships, each one falling underneath that which preceded it.
Screenshot of current results attached.

Attached is a screenshot of the pivot table when only one browser is selected, but I'd like to produce this same product as a summary for all.

1. Row labels in first column
2. Count of each label in second column

[image: What I'd like to see but for all browsers]

[image: Actual result with parent/child appearance]

[image: original table of UAT]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a pivot table, consider using `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIF(range, "F")
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS(criteria range 1, " F", criteria range 2, "UAT 2 Desk")
```

You could set up a summary worksheet or table that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure I understand your problem well, but perhaps here an input how to design your raw data table.

If you want to pivot your datas, make sure that the table structure of the data source is appropriate.

Consider this table form for your data collection

```
Test area, Test Case, Tester name, Platform, Test result
```

It results that you have one row for each single result.

Having this structure, you are much more flexible for pivoting datas.